# Create alias for command containing single quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

im trying to create alias for this command

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" `echo $file | tr ' ' '_'` ; done
```

Im using this command to create alias

```
alias renfiles="for file in *; do mv "$file" `echo $file | tr ' ' '_'` ; done"
```

But it creates alias for wrong command :

```
$ which renfiles
alias renfiles='for file in *; do mv * * ; done'
```

What i would like to do is to create one alias that rename files then list them using readlink, so one alias to do below :

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" `echo $file | tr ' ' '_'` ; done
for f in *; do   readlink -f -- "$f"; done | sed -e "s/\/home\/ovh\/www/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/g"
```

Comment: Use a function instead of an alias, you don't have to worry about any quoting issues.

Comment: Do you have the `rename` command installed? Then you don't need to write your own loop.

Answer (score 4):

Use a function instead:

```
renfiles () {
  for file in ./*; do
    mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | tr ' ' '_')"
  done
}
```

You can write this more simply in `bash` as

```
renfiles () {
  for file in ./*; do
    mv "$file" "${file// /_}"
  done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alias renfiles="for file in *; do mv "$file" `echo $file | tr ' ' '_'` ; done"
```

1) You have two quoted strings there (marked), the expansion of `$file` is outside any quotes. Which means that it will be expanded when the alias is *set*, not when it's executed. (It would be expanded from within the double-quotes, too)

2) Backticks (as well as the saner `$(...)`) are expanded from inside double-quotes, so they also get expanded when the alias is set. So, if `$file` happened to contain a `*` when the alias was set, you'd get exactly what you saw.

If you want to do something like that with an alias, use single quotes around it:

```
alias renfiles='for file in *; do echo mv "$file" $(echo $file | tr " " "_") ; done'
```

(Or better yet, use a function like @chepner showed.)